# What's wrong with a JavaScript class whose constructor returns a function or an object

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I use `new` to instainciate an instance of a certain class, I got the actual instance. When the constructor function has a return value, the `new` sentence gives out the actual instance also. However, when the constructor returns itself, I can't get the instance. Instead I get the constructor. I wander what's wrong with this.

Here are my test code fragment:

```
function foo() {
    this.x = 1;
    return foo;
}
console.log(new foo()); // prints the defination of foo
```

---

As we consider, in most situations, it makes no sence to return a function like this. However, why does JS has such a feature? Is there any consideration when designing JS? Or is it just a bug of JS?

Comment: _"I wander what's wrong with this."_ The biggest thing that's wrong with it is that it makes no sense. Why would you return a constructor from itself?

Answer (score 3):

If you return an object from a constructor, the result of the `new ...` expression will be the object you returned:

```js
function myWackyConstructor() {
  return new Date();
}

var d = new myWackyConstructor();
console.log(d);
```

If you return a primitive, the result will be the constructed object:

```js
function myWackyConstructor() {
  this.gotAValue = true;

  return 3;
}

var v = new myWackyConstructor();
console.log(v.gotAValue);
```

Typically, you should not return anything from a constructor:

```js
function myNormalConstructor() {
  this.gotAValue = true;
}

var v = new myNormalConstructor();
console.log(v.gotAValue);
```

The question is, *why* are you returning the constructor from itself?

Comment: A good exception to return something: `if(this.constructor!==TheConstructor){return new this.constructor(arg1,arg2);...}`

Comment: Thank u! In fact, I don't know why. I was just taking a quiz on JS features and this is one of the questions. But I really also want to know, does this design of JS make sence? Could you please give some explainations or references? :)

Comment: When I'm confused by this, the first issue I considered was: The `String` function can return a JS string, and it will create a `String` instance with `new`. Consider the situation that I need such a function: When I call it as a normal function it returns a specific object, such as an instance of `Date`. Just like the first example you give. On the other hand, when use it as a constructor I want the constructed object instead of the return object. This situation do make sence, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does raise an eyebrow. It does not make sense to me why you would return a static class in your constructor.

I think if you returned the actual instance it might make more sense to you but it isn't necessary.

example

```
function foo() {
    this.x = 1;
    return this;
}

var aFooInstance = new foo();

console.log(aFooInstance); // prints a instance of foo
```

However, you might want to have private variables so you can return an object like so, in this example you can also pass in the data to the constructor.

```
function foo(x) {

    var _x = x;

    this.getX = function(){ return _x;}      
}

var aFooInstance = new foo(1);

console.log(aFooInstance.getX()); // prints 1
```

I would suggest reading more on [simple class instantiation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/).

Comment: There's no reason to return `this` from a constructor function, and there's no sense in using `new` if you return something other than the constructed object.

Comment: hey @JLRishe yeah i agree you dont need to `return this`, for clarity i thought it would help the author understand whats happening. However in my 2nd example there is a point, and that is access modifiers.. or 'private variables' :) No code can directly change the value of `_x` on an instance.

Comment: Yes, but the value returned will not inherit from `foo` and will not have its prototype, so using `new` there is meaningless and confusing. If you want to have private variables and `new`, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/rrrjqsq0/

Comment: @JLRishe yeah thats a better way.. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, when we declare a function as a class and when we create an object of that class, that function gets called first.

Dont return from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript constructor does not need a return. This will work:-

```
function foo() {
    this.x = 1;
}

var myfoo = new foo();
console.log(myfoo.x);
```