# Why do constructor functions return objects, but not primitives in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to understand JavaScript's (or at least V8's) behaviour regarding constructor functions.

I know, JavaScript constructor functions should never return anything (so: `undefined`).

But consider this JavaScript:

```
function Thing() { 
  return '';
}
var t = new Thing();
console.log(t, typeof t); // => Thing {} "object"
```

Now, if you do this:

```
function Thing() { 
  return { hi: '' };
}
var t = new Thing();
console.log(t, typeof t); // => Object {hi: ""} "object"
```

And even:

```
function Thing() { 
  this.a = 'a';
  return { hi: '' };
}
var t = new Thing();
console.log(t, typeof t); // => Object {hi: ""} "object"
```

So, why does a constructor function in JavaScript return an object, but not a primitive, if you write this kind of code?

---

This behaviour is also mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006924/209232), but not explained. I've also scrolled over [The new Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-new-operator) part of the ECMAScript specification, and its [Construct](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-construct) snipped, but this was not enlightening.

Any hints or knowledge (in plain English, please)?

Comment: Well for one, it's not "wrong and ugly" because it's not doing what you think it is. And why would it return a primitive when it's not a primitive object?

Comment: In a nutshell: if you return a primitive from a constructor, it is ignored. If you return an object, it is used as the resulting object. Does that answer the question? Or are you looking for a rationale for this behaviour?

Comment: It behaves this way "because the spec says so".  However, I think the "why" explanation that you're looking for may be opinion based really - you'd need to get an answer that shows the language design team's reasoning, anything else is just someone's opinion - for example, here's mine: you've called `new` so you're expecting an object, perhaps the language design team felt that you should always get an object, even if the function returns a primitive, but I have nothing solid to back that reasoning.

Comment: Continuing @James' reasoning... a function may return something like `true` or `false` as a side effect, which can safely be ignored; but if a "serious" object is returned, that should probably be the return value for an *object constructor function*.

Comment: I even did not found the place in the spec, where this behaviour is defined.

Comment: @malte The [`new` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) calls [\[\[Construct\]\]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2), which does this.

Comment: @Oriol Excerpt from your link: `9. If Type(result) is Object then return result.
10. Return obj.`

Comment: It helps with shimming. `if (!window.foo) window.foo = function() { return { bar: function() { ...} } };`

Comment: @jib Chicken and egg... You can write it like that because you can write it like that. If you couldn't you wouldn't. :)

Comment: @deceze there are cases shiming browser objects where I don't see another way to do it, such as: https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/src/js/firefox/firefox_shim.js#L58

Comment: @jib There's always another way to write it: `window.foo = (function () { .. return Foo; })()`. Or I'm not understanding how this relates to the question.

Comment: @deceze I can imagine cases where one would need to modify the browser object after creating it, but before returning it: e.g. `window.foo = function() { var org = new mozFoo(); org.bar = x; return org; }` - The relevance is that the JS behavior we're discussing means the `new foo()` pattern is acting both as a constructor and a factory function, which is helpful when shimming what should be "returned".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because, by definition, the purpose of constructors is producing objects, not primitives:

> [**4.3.4 constructor**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.4)
>
> function object that creates and initialises objects

Therefore, the [[[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) internal method (called via the [`new` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2)), checks the type of the value returned by [[[Call]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1):

> [**13.2.2 [[Construct]]**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2)
>
> 8. Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of *F*, providing *obj* as the **this** value and providing
>      the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as *args*.
> 9. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*result*) is Object then return *result*.
> 10. Return *obj*.

In fact, this is an [invariant](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-invariants-of-the-essential-internal-methods):

> **[[Construct]] ( )**
>
> - The Type of the return value must be Object.

Comment: Like the link in your comment. I didn't spot that. Thanks. It does not make much sense in my view - but this is not the place for opinions :) .